# Взаимодействие с отдельными векторными примитивами SVG в Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, svg

Можно ли в Android интерактивно взаимодействовать с отдельными примитивами SVG?
Например поместить на какой нибудь Layout векторное изображение, отрисованное в SVG, в котором нужные примитивы, отмечены каким-то тегом. Затем отслеживать действия пользователя и, например, после нажатия на примитив, получать его идентификатор, чтобы выполнить операцию, зависящую от примитива.